# JavaFx File Chooser - File open dialog is not opening in a single click

Tags: java, javafx, scenebuilder

[image]I am trying to open a File Open Dialog by the click of a button as in the below screenshot:

When I am clicking the Select File Button, the File open dialog doesn't open on the first click. I have to click it once more to open the file dialog window.

My code setup is as per below:

**Main.java**

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    public void start(final Stage stage) throws Exception {
        Parent root = (Parent) javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(getClass()
                .getResource("xPressionTestClient-GUI.fxml"));
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        stage.setTitle("xPression Test Client");
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.setResizable(false);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
```

**FXML Controller.java**

```
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.stage.FileChooser;

public class FXMLController {
    @FXML
    private Button inputXmlFileBtn;
    @FXML
    private TextField inputXmlName;
    //private Stage savedStage;
    final FileChooser fileChooser = new FileChooser();
    @FXML
    public void inputXmlFileChooser(){

        inputXmlFileBtn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                //Show open file dialog
                File file = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(null);

                //Set the path for inputXmlName text field
                inputXmlName.setText(file.getPath());
            }
        });
        //savedStage = stage;
        //inputXmlName.setText("Hello");
    }
```

**FXML Code:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import java.lang.String?>
<?import javafx.collections.FXCollections?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Tab?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TabPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.Pane?>
<?import javafx.scene.shape.Line?>
<?import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>

<Pane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="660.0" prefWidth="782.0" style="-fx-background-color: white;" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/9.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="com.lowes.xpression.application.FXMLController">
   <children>
      <Label layoutX="319.0" layoutY="14.0" text="xPression Test Client">
         <font>
            <Font name="Calibri Bold" size="16.0" />
         </font>
      </Label>
      <Rectangle arcHeight="5.0" arcWidth="5.0" fill="WHITE" height="565.0" layoutX="14.0" layoutY="45.0" stroke="BLACK" strokeType="INSIDE" width="748.0" />
      <Label layoutX="28.0" layoutY="72.0" text="Input XML File">
         <font>
            <Font name="Segoe UI Bold" size="14.0" />
         </font>
      </Label>
      <TextField fx:id="inputXmlName" layoutX="202.0" layoutY="68.0" prefHeight="26.0" prefWidth="371.0" promptText="Input XML" />
      <Button fx:id="inputXmlFileBtn" layoutX="596.0" layoutY="69.0" onAction="#inputXmlFileChooser" onmnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="96.0" text="Select File" />
      <Label layoutX="28.0" layoutY="107.0" text="Output XML File Name">
         <font>
            <Font name="Segoe UI Bold" size="14.0" />
         </font>
      </Label>
      <TextField fx:id="outputXmlName" layoutX="202.0" layoutY="103.0" prefHeight="26.0" prefWidth="371.0" promptText="Output XML File Name" />

      <Label layoutX="344.0" layoutY="646.0" text="Â© CopyRight 2018">
         <font>
            <Font name="Calibri Bold Italic" size="12.5" />
         </font>
      </Label>
      <TabPane fx:id="XmlData" layoutX="28.0" layoutY="148.0" prefHeight="448.0" prefWidth="726.0" tabClosingPolicy="UNAVAILABLE">
        <tabs>
          <Tab text="Vendor Header &amp; FeatureBenefits">
            <content>
              <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="180.0" prefWidth="200.0">
                     <children>
                        <Label layoutX="29.0" layoutY="14.0" text="Vendor Header">
                           <font>
                              <Font name="Segoe UI Bold" size="14.0" />
                           </font>
                        </Label>
                        <Line endX="100.0" layoutX="129.0" layoutY="34.0" startX="-100.0" />
                        <Label layoutX="29.0" layoutY="48.0" text="Vendor Header1">
                           <font>
                              <Font name="Segoe UI Bold" size="14.0" />
                           </font>
                        </Label>
                        <TextField fx:id="VendorHeader1" layoutX="29.0" layoutY="71.0" prefHeight="26.0" prefWidth="305.0" promptText="VendorHeader1" />
                        <Label layoutX="383.0" layoutY="48.0" text="Vendor Header2">
                           <font>
                              <Font name="Segoe UI Bold" size="14.0" />
                           </font>
                        </Label>
                        <TextField fx:id="VendorHeader2" layoutX="383.0" layoutY="71.0" prefHeight="26.0" prefWidth="305.0" promptText="VendorHeader2" />
                        <ComboBox fx:id="envCombo1" layoutX="29.0" layoutY="340.0" prefWidth="150.0" promptText="Select Environment">
                           <items>
                              <FXCollections fx:factory="observableArrayList">
                                 <String fx:value="DEV" />
                                 <String fx:value="SIT" />
                                 <String fx:value="UAT" />
                              </FXCollections>
                           </items>
                        </ComboBox>
                     </children>
                  </AnchorPane>
            </content>
          </Tab>
          <Tab text="Untitled Tab 2">
            <content>
              <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="180.0" prefWidth="200.0">
                     <children>
                        <Label text="Vendor Header1">
                           <font>
                              <Font name="Calibri Bold" size="14.0" />
                           </font>
                        </Label>
                     </children>
                  </AnchorPane>
            </content>
          </Tab>
            <Tab text="Untitled Tab 2">
               <content>
                  <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="180.0" prefWidth="200.0" />
               </content>
            </Tab>
        </tabs>
      </TabPane>
   </children>
</Pane>
```

What should be fixed so that the above issue can be solved?

Comment: Your code seems incomplete. The `inputXmlFileChooser()` isn't called from anywhere - so I don't understand how this can be showing the file chooser at all, first click or second..

Comment: @James_D Thanks for pointing that out! Have updated the code.

Comment: Please see [Pretend you're talking to a busy colleague](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [mcve]. The code posted does not run, and includes way more than the minimal needed to demonstrate the problem, so basically instead of helping, we are wasting time.

Comment: @James_D  I would suggest to reopen. I see the problem and it is different than the "duplicate" one.

Comment: @c0der How is it different? The OP is registering a handler method which sets the handler, exactly as in the linked question.

Comment: In case the answer posted is not clear:   you are setting `onAction` twice.
   Once in the fxml:  onAction="#inputXmlFileChooser"  
    and once in the controller:  inputXmlFileBtn.setOnActio` .Remove it from the controller